# how to get locationState or specifically isDisconnected value for a location in Google my business new API?

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

Where I can find the locationState info in the new google my business API?
I was using [this link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations#locationstate), but now it is deprecated. The
locationState I used to get from google my business api v4, had a structure like the photo below:
[image]

The new API which now I am using returns an object called metadata [found in this link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#Location.Metadata)
and I see that `isGoogleUpdated` has been converted into `hasGoogleUpdated`, and `isDuplicate` has been changed to `duplicateLocation`. Is the info **`isDisconnected`** still provided by Google?

Comment: Hi Shila, Disconnected is not a part of the official GBP statuses thus I think it's why it has been deprecated, however in the Verifications API they have added recommendationReason part of the ComplyWithGuidelines object which indicates if the business is Suspended or Disabled -> https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/verifications/rest/v1/locations/getVoiceOfMerchantState#complywithguidelines. Hope this helps.